# Django & MariaDB/MySQL: Does select_for_update lock rows from subqueries? Causing deadlocks?

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, mariadb

Software: Django 2.1.0, Python 3.7.1, MariaDB 10.3.8, Linux Ubuntu 18LTS

We recently added some load to a new application, and starting observing lots of deadlocks.  After a lot digging, I found out that the Django select_for_update query resulted in an SQL with several subqueries (3 or 4).   In all deadlocks I've seeen so far, at least one of the transactions involves this SQL with multiple subqueries.

**my question is... Does the select_for_udpate lock records from every table involved?** In my case, would record from the main SELECT, and from other tables used by subqueries get locked? Or only records from the main SELECT?

From Django docs:

> By default, select_for_update() locks all rows that are selected by the query. For example, rows of related objects specified in select_related() are locked in addition to rows of the queryset’s model.

However, I'm not using select_related() , at least I don't put it explicitly.

Summary of my app:

```
with transaction.atomic():
   ModelName.objects.select_for_update().filter(...)
   ...
   update record that is locked
   ...
```

- 50+ clients sending queries to the database concurrently
- Some of those queries ask for the same record. Meaning different transactions will run the same SQL at the same time.

After a lot of reading, I did the following to try to get the deadlock under control:

1- Try/Catch exception error '1213' (deadlock). When this happens, wait 30 seconds and retry the query.  Here, I rely on the ROLLBACK function from the database engine.
Also, print output of SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS and SHOW PROCESSLIST. But SHOW PROCESSLIST doesn't give useful information.

2- Modify the Django select_on_update so that it doesn't build an SQL with subqueries. Now, the SQL generated contains a single WHERE with values and no subqueries.

Anything else that could be done to reduce the deadlocks?

Comment: Show us the SQL for the transaction; there are many possible ways to alleviate the issue you appear to be having.

Comment: Have the same problem (using Django 2.2), lots of 1213 Deadlock errors during select_for_update in a transaction, without any real concurrency going on. It happens far too often for it to be an actual deadlock. Difficult to debug :/

Comment: @BjornW - something that helped me was looking at the actual SQL query created by django. In my case, Django created subquieries unnecessarily.  I replaced those subqueries with a simple WHERE statement, also made sure to use  index.

Comment: @freeAR hmm yes I did check these, what is happening (in my case) is that inside the transaction.atomic, where I do the select_for_update, I do some other ops on objects related to the locked object. the SQL for these are not "locking" though (I'm a bit confused if/when django also row-locks the related objects), and I guess a concurrent access to these related objects by another thread could cause a deadlock. I'm just too clueless regarding the different kinds of lockings inside InnoDB and how they map to SQL and DJango syntax. All tutorials kind of gloss over these details :)

Comment: @BjornW ... I agree, this information is hard to find. I found bits of useful information in different stackoverflow cases , but I spent tons of hours.  Did you try printing the output of ' SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS ' when a deadlock exception is caught?   It helped me finding out which queries caused the deadlock.

Comment: @freeAR hmm yeah some kind of more in-depth trace on why the deadlock occured would be immensely helpful. it wasn't available in my Sentry logs (they just show the SQL statements from the thread that got the deadlock, and understandably not from the other threads that could be involved). is there a way to configure mysql to print a more extensive log every time this happens in some way? I'm using AWS RDS though but it does provide all the logs. Would the SHOW ENGINE STATUS command actually show deadlock info from the past?

Answer (score 0):

If u hv select_for_update inside a transaction, it will only be released went the whole transaction commits or rollbacks. With nowait set to true the other concurrent requests will immediately fail with:
3572, 'Statement aborted because lock(s) could not be acquired immediately and NOWAIT is set.')

So if we cant use optimistic locks and cannot make transactions shorter, we can set nowait=true in our select_for_update, and we will see a lot of failures if our assumptions are correct. Here we can just catch deadlock failures and retry them with backoff strategy. This is based on the assumption that all people are trying to write to the same thing like an auction item, or ticket booking with a short window of time. If that is not the case consider changing the db design a bit to make deadlocks common